# Mark a message as deleted using gem Mail [POP3]

Tags: ruby, email

I use gem [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail). My code:

```
Mail.defaults do
    retriever_method :pop3, :address => CONFIG_FILE["mail_params"]["address"],
                     :port => CONFIG_FILE["mail_params"]["port"],
                     :user_name => CONFIG_FILE["mail_params"]["user_name"],
                     :password => CONFIG_FILE["mail_params"]["password"],
                     :enable_ssl => CONFIG_FILE["mail_params"]["enable_ssl"]
end

emails = Mail.all(:order => :asc)

emails.each do |mail|
   #do something 
end
```

How can I mark removed only one letter mail in my cycle? Like this `mail.delete`. I want, if errors in processing the letters not, remove it, otherwise leave. 
The documentation contains just one method to delete all messages `Mail.delete_all`